# Django and Twitter request_token

Tags: django, twitter, oauth

I am stuck with twitter signing in. By now I realized, that it is a several step thing (rather stupid in comparison with OAuth2):

1. Make a POST request to /request_token endpoint in order to get the initial token
2. Redirect user to /authenticate with token param from (1) in order to get another token
3. Make another POST request to /access-token with token from (2) and finally get the desired token.

Right now I am a bit stuck with (1): twitter API always returns ERROR 215, Bad Authentication Data.

The code is like this:

```
    key = b"my_key&"
    raw_init = "POST" + "&" + quote("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/oauth/request_token", safe='')
    time_param = str(calendar.timegm(time.gmtime()))
    raw_params = quote('oauth_callback', safe='') + "=" + quote('http://example.com/twitter-auth/', safe='')
    raw_params += "&" + quote('oauth_consumer_key', safe='') + "=" + quote('consumer_key', safe='')
    raw_params += "&" + quote('oauth_nonce', safe='') + "=" + quote('aAbBcDadadwrwwrwrwr', safe='')
    raw_params += "&" + quote('oauth_signature_method', safe='') + "=" + quote('HMAC-SHA1', safe='')
    raw_params += "&" + quote('oauth_timestamp', safe='') + "=" + quote(time_param, safe='')
    raw_params += "&" + quote('oauth_version', safe='') + "=" + quote('1.0', safe='')
    #
    raw_params = quote(raw_params, safe='')
    raw_final = bytes(raw_init + "&" + raw_params, encoding='utf-8')
    hashed = hmac.new(key, raw_final, sha1)

    request.raw_final = hashed

    request.auth_header = base64.b64encode(hashed.digest()).decode()
```

The code above make the signature for the Authorization header.

The POST request:

```
    url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/oauth/request_token'
    data = {}
    oauth_sign_method = "HMAC-SHA1"

    headers = {'Authorization': 'OAuth oauth_nonce="aAbBcDadadwrwwrwrwr"' +
                                'oauth_callback="' + quote('http://example.com/twitter-auth/', safe='') + '",' +
                                'oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",' +
                                'oauth_timestamp="' + time_param + '",'+
                                'oauth_consumer_key="consumer_key",'+
                                'oauth_signature="' + base64.b64encode(hashed.digest()).decode() + '",'+
                                'oauth_version="1.0"'}

    r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)

    answer = json.loads(r.text)

    request.twitter_answer = answer
```

And the answer is always with error 215 - Bad Authentication Data. Any idea why?

Comment: @DanielRoseman which of them have such functions? tweepy?

Comment: I think Twython is maintained more actively

Comment: @souldeux thank you very much! several lines of code and its working :-)

Answer (score 0):

I am also building Django backend for twitter oauth.

Please go here and check the python code, I succeeded with that code snippet.

[Python code for getting twitter request_token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10081327/retrieving-a-request-token-from-the-twitter-api-with-python-3)